# JavaScript: Is there any way to print outputs without newline?

Tags: javascript, rhino

I am learning JavaScript and I am trying to print this particular sequence of hashes:

```
#
##
###
```

I wrote this piece of code to produce the sequence:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for(let j = 0; j <= i; j++){
        print('#');
    }
    print('\n');
}
```

Note: I am using rhino to execute the program on my Ubuntu terminal.

```
rhino <filename>.js              //Command used to execute JavaScript file.
```

The output I obtain:

```
#


#
#


#
#
#
```

I obtain the correct output with this program:

```
var starString = "";
for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for(let j = 0; j <= i; j++){
        starString += '#';
    }
    print(starString);
    starString = "";
}
```

My question is this: Is there a print statement which I can use that does not add a newline at the end of the statement?

Answer (score 0):

No, not directly using `print()`. However you can make your own function using `System.out.print()` that prints without the new lines:

```
function printNOn(arg) {
     java.lang.System.out.print(arg)
}
```

result:

```
MBP:rhino1_7R4 mark$ java -jar js.jar
Rhino 1.7 release 4 2012 06 18
js> function printNOn(arg) {
     java.lang.System.out.print(arg)
} 
js> for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
  >     for(let j = 0; j <= i; j++){
  >         printNOn("#")
  >     }
  >     printNOn('\n')
  > }
#
##
###
js>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log('Node js - hello world');
for(var counter = 0; counter< 5 ;counter++){
    // console.log("----------------");
    var pound = "#";
    for(var localcounter = 0; localcounter < counter; localcounter++ ){

      //console.log("localcounter is ", localcounter);
       //console.log("counter is ", counter);
      //console.log(pound);
      pound += "#";
      //console.log(pound);
    }
    console.log(pound);
    //console.log("----------------");

    //
    pound = "";
    pound = null;
}
```